# Generar Totales de forma Vertical SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, pivot

Este es el select usando PIVOT

```
select codp, Anho, isnull([1],0) as Enero,
isnull([2],0) as Febrero,
isnull([3],0) as Marzo,
isnull([4],0) as Abril,
isnull([5],0) as Mayo,
isnull([6],0)as Junio,
isnull([7],0) as Julio,
isnull([8],0) as Agosto, 
isnull([9],0)as Septiembre,
isnull([10],0)as Octubre,
isnull([11],0)as Noviembre,
isnull([12],0) as Diciembre,
isnull([1],0)+isnull([2],0)+isnull([3],0)+isnull([4],0)+isnull([5],0)+isnull([6],0)+isnull([7],0)+isnull([8],0)+isnull([9],0)+isnull([10],0)+isnull([11],0)+
isnull([12],0) as Totales
from (  select codp, year(t.fecha) as Anho, MONTH(t.fecha) as Mes, t.recaudacion as Recaudacion
    from TAQUILLA t
    where year(t.fecha) = 1991) 
    as aux
pivot (sum(Recaudacion) 
for Mes in ([1],[2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],[11], [12])) as pvt
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual me trae el resultado total por código (cod) de película de todos los meses 
Ahora necesito que me sume toda la fila de Enero y me muestre la suma abajo 
como en la siguiente imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr esa forma de calculo se tienen que seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Tu tabla tiene que estar como la siguiente imagen pueden ser una temporal como la que he creado TMP_RECAUDACION:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Ejecutar el siguiente script:

> ```
> DECLARE @COLUMNASISNULL NVARCHAR(MAX),@COLUMNAS NVARCHAR(MAX),@COLUMNASSUM NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
> SET @COLUMNASISNULL = STUFF(
> (
>     SELECT ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(MES) + ','''') AS '+QUOTENAME(MES)
>     FROM
>     (
>   SELECT DISTINCT 
>                MES,NRO_MES
>         FROM TMP_RECAUDACION AS S 
>     ) AS x ORDER BY X.NRO_MES FOR XML PATH('')    
> ), 1, 1, '');
>
> SET @COLUMNAS = STUFF(
> (
>     SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(MES)
>     FROM
>     (
>   SELECT DISTINCT 
>                MES,NRO_MES
>         FROM TMP_RECAUDACION AS S 
>     ) AS x ORDER BY X.NRO_MES FOR XML PATH('')    
> ), 1, 1, '');
>
> SET @COLUMNASSUM = STUFF(
> (
>     SELECT ',SUM(' + QUOTENAME(MES)+')AS '+QUOTENAME(MES)
>     FROM
>     (
>   SELECT DISTINCT 
>                MES,NRO_MES
>         FROM TMP_RECAUDACION AS S 
>     ) AS x ORDER BY X.NRO_MES FOR XML PATH('')    
> ), 1, 1, '');
>
> SET @sql = N'
> SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), COATI), '''') AS COATI, 
>        ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ANO), ''Totales'') ANO, 
>        ' + @COLUMNAS + '
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT COATI, 
>            ANO, 
>            GROUPING(ANO) AS G_ANO, 
>             ' + @COLUMNASSUM + '
>     FROM
>     (
>         SELECT PV.COATI, 
>                PV.ANO, 
>                ' + @COLUMNASISNULL + '
>         FROM
>         (
>             SELECT *
>             FROM TMP_RECAUDACION AS S
>         ) AS TP PIVOT(SUM(RECAUDACION) FOR MES IN(' + @COLUMNAS + ')) AS PV
>     ) AS X
>     GROUP BY COATI, 
>              ANO WITH ROLLUP
> ) AS X2
> WHERE(X2.G_ANO = 0
>       OR X2.COATI IS NULL);
> ';
> PRINT @sql;
> EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
> ```

quedara de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta es una solución dinámica a un problema que no lo necesita. Además de que el hecho de usar una tabla adicional incrementa el tiempo, la lectura y la escritura.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas explotar tu consulta dos veces, una para el detalle y otra para los totales. Puedes aprovechar que a partir de SQL Server 2005 se introdujo lo que se conoce como [COMMOM TABLE EXPRESSION](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    Select  codp, 
            Anho, 
            isnull([1],0) as Enero,
            isnull([2],0) as Febrero,
            isnull([3],0) as Marzo,
            isnull([4],0) as Abril,
            isnull([5],0) as Mayo,
            isnull([6],0)as Junio,
            isnull([7],0) as Julio,
            isnull([8],0) as Agosto, 
            isnull([9],0)as Septiembre,
            isnull([10],0)as Octubre,
            isnull([11],0)as Noviembre,
            isnull([12],0) as Diciembre,
            isnull([1],0)+isnull([2],0)+isnull([3],0)+isnull([4],0)+isnull([5],0)+isnull([6],0)+isnull([7],0)+isnull([8],0)+isnull([9],0)+isnull([10],0)+isnull([11],0)+
                isnull([12],0) as Totales
            from (select codp, 
                        year(t.fecha) as Anho, 
                        MONTH(t.fecha) as Mes, 
                        t.recaudacion as Recaudacion
                    from TAQUILLA t
                    where year(t.fecha) = 1991
                ) as aux
            pivot (sum(Recaudacion) for Mes in ([1],[2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],[11], [12])) as pvt
)
SELECT  codp,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Anho) AS 'Anho',
        Enero, 
        Febrero, 
        Marzo, 
        Abril, 
        Junio, 
        Julio, 
        Agosto, 
        Septiembre, 
        Octubre, 
        Noviembre, 
        Diciembre,
        1 as Orden
        FROM CTE

UNION

SELECT  NULL
        'totales'       AS 'detalle',
        SUM(Enero), 
        SUM(Febrero), 
        SUM(Marzo), 
        SUM(Abril), 
        SUM(Junio), 
        SUM(Julio), 
        SUM(Agosto), 
        SUM(Septiembre), 
        SUM(Octubre), 
        SUM(Noviembre), 
        SUM(Diciembre),
        2 as orden
        FROM CTE
        GROUP BY codp
        ORDER BY orden
```

Lo que hacemos, básicamente es darle un alias a tu consulta original y aprovecharlo para obtener el detalle original y luego mediante un `UNION` agregar los totales.

Sin este tipo de clausula, también se puede resolver, pero con algo más de trabajo, ya que deberíamos en primer lugar insertar los datos en una tabla temporal para luego si, aprovecharlos tanto para el detalle como para los totales

Answer (score 0):

Una de las razones por las que evito usar la instrucción `PIVOT` es por la poca flexibilidad que ofrece comparado con la alternativa que tenemos disponible desde antes del 2000.

Una de las ventajas, es la capacidad de utilizar las opciones avanzadas de GROUP BY que permiten organizar mejor nuestros datos y evitar tener que leer la tabla más de una vez. Verás que he cambiado tu consulta pero los datos se mantienen constantes.

```
WITH ctePreAgregadoTaquilla AS(
    --Uso un preagregado porque suele incrementar el rendimiento durante el pivoteo de datos
    SELECT t.codp,
        YEAR( t.fecha) AS Anho,
        MONTH( t.fecha) AS Mes,
        SUM(t.recaudacion) AS Recaudacion
    FROM Taquilla t
    WHERE t.fecha >= '19910101' --Usar rangos en vez de funciones sobre columnas
    AND t.fecha < '19920101'    --Eso permite que se pueda utilizar un índice y estadísticas en caso de existir.
    GROUP BY t.codp,
        YEAR( t.fecha),
        MONTH( t.fecha)
)
SELECT ISNULL( CAST( codp AS varchar(10)), 'Total') AS codp,
    Anho,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes =  1 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Enero,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes =  2 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Febrero,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes =  3 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Marzo,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes =  4 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Abril,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes =  5 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Mayo,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes =  6 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Junio,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes =  7 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Julio,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes =  8 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Agosto, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes =  9 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Septiembre,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes = 10 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Octubre,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes = 11 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Noviembre,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes = 12 THEN Recaudacion ELSE 0 END) AS Diciembre,
    SUM( Recaudacion) AS Totales
FROM ctePreAgregadoTaquilla
--En vez de tener una lectura adicional a la tabla, se especifica como se agruparán los datos.
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(codp, Anho), (Anho);
```

Aquí abajo agrego el código de creación y llenado de la tabla con un millón de filas para quien quiera comprobar el rendimiento. Según mis pruebas, hay una mejora de casi 3 veces mayor rapidez con el método original y hasta entre 5 y 8 veces más rapidez con las otras soluciones.

```
CREATE TABLE Taquilla(
    codp        int, 
    fecha       date,
    recaudacion float
)
GO
INSERT INTO Taquilla
SELECT TOP(1000000)
        ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5 + 1,
       DATEADD( DD, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 365, '1991'),
       ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100000
FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

**Con esto resolví el problema**

```
WITH 
totales (codp,anho,Enero,Febrero,Marzo,Abril,Mayo,Junio,Julio,Agosto,Septimbre,Octubre,Noviembre,Diciembre,Totales) AS 
 (Select  codp, 
        Anho, 
        isnull([1],0) as Enero,
        isnull([2],0) as Febrero,
        isnull([3],0) as Marzo,
        isnull([4],0) as Abril,
        isnull([5],0) as Mayo,
        isnull([6],0)as Junio,
        isnull([7],0) as Julio,
        isnull([8],0) as Agosto, 
        isnull([9],0)as Septiembre,
        isnull([10],0)as Octubre,
        isnull([11],0)as Noviembre,
        isnull([12],0) as Diciembre,
        isnull([1],0)+isnull([2],0)+isnull([3],0)+isnull([4],0)+isnull([5],0)+isnull([6],0)+isnull([7],0)+isnull([8],0)+isnull([9],0)+isnull([10],0)+isnull([11],0)+
        isnull([12],0) as Totales
        from (select codp, 
                    year(t.fecha) as Anho, 
                    MONTH(t.fecha) as Mes, 
                    t.recaudacion as Recaudacion
                from TAQUILLA t
                --where year(t.fecha) = 1991
            ) as aux
        pivot (sum(Recaudacion) for Mes in ([1],[2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],[11], [12])) as pvt),

detalles (codp, anho,Enero,Febrero,Marzo,Abril,Mayo,Junio,Julio,Agosto,Septimbre,Octubre,Noviembre,Diciembre,totales) as
(select CODP, ANHO, ISNULL([1],0)ENERO,
ISNULL([2],0)FEBRERO,
ISNULL([3],0)MARZO,
ISNULL([4],0)ABRIL,
ISNULL([5],0)MAYO,
ISNULL([6],0)JUNIO,
ISNULL([7],0)JULIO,
ISNULL([8],0)AGOSTO,
ISNULL([9],0)SEPTIEMBRE,
ISNULL([10],0)OCTUBRE,
ISNULL([11],0)NOVIEMBRE,
ISNULL([12],0)DICIEMBRE,            
/*TOTAL*/

ISNULL([1],0)+ISNULL([2],0)+ISNULL([3],0)+ISNULL([4],0)+ ISNULL([5],0)+ISNULL([6],0)+ISNULL([7],0)+ISNULL([8],0)+
ISNULL([9],0)+ISNULL([10],0)+ISNULL([11],0)+ISNULL([12],0) AS TOTAL

from (
    SELECT CODP,YEAR(FECHA) ANHO ,MONTH(FECHA) MES, SUM(RECAUDACION) as rec
    FROM TAQUILLA
    --where codp is not null
    GROUP BY grouping sets(CODP,YEAR(FECHA),MONTH(FECHA))
    having YEAR(FECHA) IS NULL --AND MONTH(FECHA) IS NULL
    and codp is null

    ) AS TABLA

PIVOT
(   
    sum(REC)
    FOR MES IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) as P)

select convert(varchar(10),t.codp) as codp,convert(varchar(10),t.anho) as Anho,t.Enero,t.Febrero,t.Marzo,t.Abril,t.Mayo,t.Junio,t.Julio,t.Agosto,t.Septimbre,t.Octubre,t.Noviembre,t.Diciembre,t.Totales
from totales t

union 

select ' ' as codp,'Totales',d.Enero,d.Febrero,d.Marzo,d.Abril,d.Mayo,d.Junio,d.Julio,d.Agosto,d.Septimbre,d.Octubre,d.Noviembre,d.Diciembre,d.Totales
from detalles d
order by totales
go
```